# FlexBox aligning items

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I'm trying to align the 6th, 7th, 8th, 9th items in the flex container to
get this:

[1th 2th 3th 4th 5th.............6th 7th 8th 9h].

I was trying with margin-right: auto but it doesn't work for a group of items.

```css
.upper_nav ul {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.upper_nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.6em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #4d4d4d;
}
```

```html
<nav class="upper_nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#Clients.html">Individual Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Companies">Companies</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Corporations.html">Corporations</a></li>
    <li><a href="#VIP.html">VIP</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Private Banking.html">Private Banking</a></li>

    <li><a href="#EN">EN</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Order via Internet">Order via Internet</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Sign in">Sign in</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

My full code is here: https://codepen.io/mario1982/pen/wrELoB

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276

Answer (score 1):

You could split the navigation into two parts and add `flexbox` properties on the container to separate them. If you want to add items to the menu in the future you won't have to worry about `nth-child` causing problems.

```css
.upper_nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.upper_nav ul {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.upper_nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.6em;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #4d4d4d;
}
```

```html
<nav class="upper_nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#Clients.html">Individual Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Companies">Companies</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Corporations.html">Corporations</a></li>
    <li><a href="#VIP.html">VIP</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Private Banking.html">Private Banking</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#EN">EN</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Order via Internet">Order via Internet</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Sign in">Sign in</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it was easy, the 6th item should get "margin-left: auto", and that's all.

Comment: also could do 

`div:nth-child(6n) {
  margin-left: auto;
}`

Comment: The `margin-right: auto` will also work, when put on the 5th item